# How do I get the current time in Swatch Internet Time in Java?

Tags: java, time

How do I get the current time in [**.beats**](http://www.swatch.com/gb_en/internettime/) ([Swatch Internet Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time)) in Java?

Comment: releated http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85084/calculate-swatch-internet-time

Comment: awesome, I just learned this time existed from my Swatch. I honestly thought before it had to do with high/low tides ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, the formula to calculate the current time in .beats is:

> beats = ( UTC+1seconds + ( UTC+1minutes * 60 ) + ( UTC+1hours * 3600 ) ) / 86,4

Round it down and you have the current time in .beats.

## New Java Code (java.time)

In Java 8 and later, we have the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), extended by [ThreeTen Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project).

```
public static int getCurrentTimeInBeats() {
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "UTC+01:00" ) );  // "Biel Meantime" = UTC+01:00
    int beats = (int) ( ( now.get( ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE) + ( now.get( ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR ) * 60 ) + ( now.get( ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 3600 ) ) / 86.4 );
    return beats;
}
```

## Old Java Code

If you cannot use the new java.time package in Java 8 and later, you can use the date-time classes first bundled with earlier versions of Java.

```
public static int getCurrentTimeInBeats() {
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance( java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT+01:00" ) );
    int beats = (int) ( ( cal.get( java.util.Calendar.SECOND ) + ( cal.get( java.util.Calendar.MINUTE ) * 60 ) + ( cal.get( java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) * 3600 ) ) / 86.4 );
    return beats;
}
```

Note that the use of "GMT" in `GMT+01:00` rather than "UTC", per the doc for [`TimeZone.getTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Hmmm, based on my research, isn't Swatch time UTC+1?

Comment: @Duncan Yup, the extra hour is manually added here. `(cal.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1)`.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is broken. I am in the UTC timezone, so if I call your function at 23:59:59, the result would be 1041 whereas it should be 41. You should change the timezone to `"UTC+1"` and remove the `+ 1` you mention in your last comment.

Comment: Finally, since this intends to be a Q&A style post, you should probably format your code so we can see all of it without scrolling. An IDE could do this for you.

Comment: @Duncan Whoops, thanks for noticing. Fixed it.

Comment: I think there is still a bug in the code: You do not ignore daylight saving time, by using CET. Swatch internet time is **not** CET, it is UTC+1 **without** DST. `cal.set(2013, 2, 31, 2, 0, 0);` and `cal.set(2013, 2, 31, 3, 0, 0);` both result to 124. You should use `Calendar.getInstance(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+1")`.

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski Oops, thanks for noticing too, fixed it! `"UTC+1"` didn't work so I used `"UTC"` and `cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);` as a workaround. Code should be bug free now.

Comment: `UTC+1` is *not* a [proper offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). Offsets must have a padding leading zero, as required by standards and by date-time libraries. So it should have been `UTC+01` or `UTC+01:00`. But experimenting with that string in Java 8 showed incorrect number of beats, too low by 42 (no kidding). The doc suggests using "GMT" as in "GMT-8:00". So in trying "GMT+01:00" I got results consistent with the .beats web site. Edited the code example above accordingly. Saved one line of code which I used to assign a `beats` variable to make the example more obvious.